# ahah not working in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6

I defined in this my menu in D6. I want to enter text field value on clicking on checkbox.

```
function mymodule_menu(){
return array(
'assignJob/js'=>array(
        'page callback' => 'assignJob_js',
        'access callback'  => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    )

}

function assignJob_assignee() {
    $output='xxxxxxx';
    drupal_json(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => $output));
}
```

While making form, there is checkbox called assignJob

```
$form[$group]['assignJob'] = array(
                    '#type' => 'checkbox',
                    '#title' => 'Assign Job',
                    '#ahah' => array(
                      'event' => 'change',
                      'path' => 'assignJob/js',
                      'wrapper' => 'edit-name',
                      'method' => 'append',
                      'effect' => 'none',
                      'progress' => array(
                        'type' => 'throbber',
                      ),
                    )
```

Wrapper is the id of text field 
When i click on this chcekbox i am getting

```
An HTTP error 404 occurred. 
/assignJob/js
```

Can anybody help me what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the path /assignJob/js doesn't exist.
make sure you don't have a typo when you declared it in hook_menu
and make sure you flushed all the caches when you change hook_menu